# How to change Selected Option to specific value on close of Overlay window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I alter the JS functions below so that the option selected on the dropdown menu reverts back to 'Australia' upon closing the overlay window.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // show popup when selecting a country from the drop-down
    var money = 0;
    $(".target").change(function () {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    money = optionSelected.attr("data-price");
    $("input[name='shipping']").val(money); 
    $('.overlay-bg').show().css({'height' : docHeight}); 
    $('.overlay-content').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'});
    });

    // hide popup when user clicks on close button
    $('.close-btn').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-bg').hide();
         // hide the overlay
    });

    // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
    $('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-bg').hide();
    })
    // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
    $('.overlay-content.').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();         
    var $this = $(this);
    var horizontalPadding = 30;
    var verticalPadding = 30;

    var iframe_popup = $('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="' + this.href + '" />');
    iframe_popup.dialog(
    {
        title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : '',
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        autoResize: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        }
    }).width(600 - horizontalPadding).height(450 - verticalPadding);
});

});
```

**HTML Drop Down Menu**

```
<div class="main-content">
<select id="customer_country" name="customer_country"
                    class="validate[required] input_styling target"
                    style="background: #FFFFFF;">
                <option value="">Please Select a Country</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan" data-price="29.95">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Åland Islands" data-price="29.95">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania" data-price="29.95">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria" data-price="29.95">Algeria</option>
                <option value="American Samoa" data-price="29.95">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="Andorra" data-price="14.95">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola" data-price="29.95">Angola</option>
                <option value="Anguilla" data-price="29.95">Anguilla</option>
                <option value="Antarctica" data-price="29.95">Antarctica</option>
                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda" data-price="29.95">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                <option value="Argentina" data-price="19.95">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Armenia" data-price="29.95">Armenia</option>
                <option value="Aruba" data-price="29.95">Aruba</option>
                <option value="Australia" data-price="19.95" selected >Australia</option>
                <option value="Austria" data-price="14.95">Austria</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I'm presuming that I need to alter this segment of code:

```
// hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
        $('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
            $('.overlay-bg').hide();
```

&&

```
  // hide popup when user clicks on close button
        $('.close-btn').click(function(){
            $('.overlay-bg').hide();
             // hide the overlay
        });
```

So the function needs to set the selected option in the drop down back to the default which is 'Australia' when the user closes the overlay window.

Please see Fiddle for the full code - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gvwg04y6/1/)

Any advice would be great.

Comment: `$('#customer_country').val('Australia')`?

Comment: That's exactly right - thanks. Would you share it as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the following to your click events:

```
$('#customer_country').val('Australia');
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected value first, then on the close of the overlay set it back to the stored value.  I also combined the button and overlay click event handlers for brevity:

```
// hide popup when user clicks on close button or the background
$('.close-btn, .overlay-bg').click(function () {
    $('.overlay-bg').hide();
    $(".target").val(prevSelected);
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gvwg04y6/2/